# Helping a starter plan customer find the best solution for 500+ indices

Tags: indices

i have a customer that is currently on a starter plan and they are looking to upgrade. here's their ideal solution with their comments:

2,000 index limit - I don't see a way around this other than totally restructuring my mobile and web app, which I currently just don't have the resources to do.
I subscribed when there wasn't an index limit (though it seems a 1,000 limit was introduced in the past few years)
My app is heavily dependent on the instantsearch library (JS and Swift) and Algolia API
500,000 records - with an understanding I'm not capped here (overages would be ok)
250,000 operations - with an understanding I'm not capped here (overages would be ok)
Virtual inducing

- cannot go on the grow plan bc of the index limit, he currently has 500+ indices

Comment: Welcome to SO. This doesn't appear to be a programming question. Looks to be about some web hosting or some api? If you do not have a specific programming question, click on the hamburger icon at the top right of this page to find another stack site.

Comment: Parts of this post appear to be about Algolia. If you want to reach their support/sales, their site is a better place to do so.